# HTML5 mode with Phonegap and AngularJS

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to make AngularJS html5 mode (true) works with Phonegap.
I did a lot of search before to post this, I tried different combination of
configurations, adding the <base/> tag in meta ( also tried with <base href="" />, <base href="/" /> and <base href="/" target="_self" /> ),
adding the .html suffix to route endpoints,adding the $delegate.history = false (like follow) inside the .config block

```
$provide.decorator('$sniffer', function($delegate) {
    $delegate.history = false;
    return $delegate;
});
```

and obviously

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

but there is no way to make it works, adding both the  tag and set html5Mode to true will result in a blank screen when application starts.
Also adding one of them will bring to the same result, blank screen.

Adding base tag with "android_asset" like follow

will make correctly load the main controller but then breaks routing....

Tested with target attribute "_blank" and "_self" values...

So my question is,
can html5 mode be enabled using Phonegap and AngularJS?

I am using cordova version 3.4.1-0.1.0 with AngularJS 1.2.16, 
tested on Android 4.0.4 real device and Android AVD 4.4.2

Any advice would be very appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on my experience and on [this comment](https://twitter.com/raymondcamden/status/438062928906825729) from Raymond Camden (who works on PhoneGap) it is not possible to use html5mode with PhoneGap + Angular.

Comment: Thank you Steve, at least a confirm that is not possible.
Do you know if there is any workaroud to port to Phonegap an already finished AngularJS application that uses html5 mode?

Comment: All I have done in the past is turn off html 5 mode. It's pretty meaningless under phonegap in any case!

Comment: I agree with you, under Phonegap it doesn't make any sense, I never wanted to say otherwise.
My point is that if I have an already finished application that uses html5 mode the porting to Phonegap it's not straight...
Anyway, thanks again for your answer!

Comment: @SergioRinaudo I realize this won't help existing code, but I think this is a vote in favor of using ui-router so that you are routing against state names rather than directly with urls.

Also, I've found that https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps, which is built on top of cordova, appears to work with html5 mode (not sure why). MCA hasn't reached a major release and I've run into a other issues while while using it, so it may not be a cure all.

Comment: I am in the same situation and the best I could do is parse JS/HTML/CSS with C# and replace links, so every time I deploy my Angular web app to mobile, I run the parser and then compile. Is there a better way? Gulp?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get around this problem with an existing website, I add a angularjs constant at build time that indicates whether or not the build is for phonegap. At config time you can access constants and choose to apply html5mode.

```
//Add this portion via your build scripts e.g. grunt or gulp
//make the constant change depending on if this is a Phonegap build or not
angular.module('myAppConstants', []).constant('PhonegapConstant', true);

//How to use
angular.module('myApp', ['myAppConstants']).config(function(
    $locationProvider,
    PhonegapConstant
) {
    if(!PhonegapConstant) {
        $locationProvider.html5mode(true);
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah but how about all links? If a link is in a template I have to use / and it obviously breaks phonegap app. Is there some tutorials how to manage single codebase for Angular/Phonegap?

Comment: @Toolkit if you use regular HTML5 mode links you can use [this a element directive](https://gist.github.com/BrainBacon/2700df3a8d8a83d19a57) to support links across both native and browser applications.

Comment: actually i am using now ui-sref="login" style

Answer (score 0):

I have just gotten this working with angularjs 1.5, the new component router, and cordova(phonegap) 6.0.

Its a bit hacky, but here's what I had to do:

1. Remove the `<base href="/">` tag from your html file.
2. Set html5 mode while setting requireBase to false

`$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });`

3. Catch the cordova(phonegap) routes

   ```
   // iOS Cordova catcher
   //
   {
       path: '/var/**',
       component: 'cordova'
   },
   // Android Cordova catcher
   //
   {
       path: '/android_asset/www/index.html',
       component: 'cordova'
   }
   ```
4. Make a cordova component which then reroutes to wherever you like.

   ```
       if(cookieService.loggedIn()) {
           $rootRouter.navigate(['Newsfeed']);
       }
       else {
           $rootRouter.navigate(['Title']);
       }
   ```

Now the rest of your routes you can use normally. I did come up against one issue with this method though, all of my local images and svgs need to start with the full path, /android_asset/www/images for android, so I made a little filter that spits out the proper asset path for web, android, and ios.